# React div scrolling is inconsistant

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am having an issue with the scrolling on one of my React forms when used on mobile devices. The div is located inside a fixed position form. Sometimes my div scrolls fine and other times the scroll seems to be broken.

You can view the app [here](https://evolv-question-form.herokuapp.com/)

The basic structure of the form is:

```
<div className={style.app}>
  <div className={style.formHolder}>
    <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>{displayPage()}</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function displayPage() {
 return (
   <>
     <div className={style.formPageContent}>
       <input />
       <input />
       <input />
       <input />
       <input />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

And the CSS:

```
.app {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-image: url("./images/Port507Bar.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.52),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93)
    ),
    url("./images/Port.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}

.formHolder {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.formPageContent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 90px;
  top: 90px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

The issue seems to occur after filling in an input field and then clicking elsewhere on the screen.

Comment: There's a scrollbar on my desktop resolution and it's locked as well - is that intended?

Comment: @AttemptedMastery It is not